# Read a file from second line till end in perl

Tags: perl

I am having a file which has so many lines. I want to discard first line and 
trying to read a file from second line till end but not getting enough help on google.
Please help me out in this case.

Below is the code in which I am trying to extract 4 and 5 column of a csv file however It is including first line that is header as well, that I do not want.

My code should get me only values not headers. that are starting from second line.

```
foreach my $inputfile (glob("$previous_path/*Analysis*.txt")) {
open(INFILE, $inputfile) or die("Could not open  file.");
foreach my $line (<INFILE>){
my @values = split(',', $line); # parse the file
my $previous_result = $values[5];
my $previous_time = $values[4];
print $previous_result,"\n";
print $previous_time,"\n";
push (@previous_result, $previous_result);
push (@previous_time, $previous_time);
    }
close(INFILE);
}
```

Comment: very simple take file into array and print that array from `array[1]` that's it

Comment: @Ram: that is a terrible solution

Comment: `scalar <$fh>` will read a line, which you can then discard at your leisure.

Comment: @Dan Dascalescu then what is the best way to do?

Comment: @Ram: That would require reading *the entire file* into memory, which user2503377 has said "has so many lines" -- terribly inefficient.

Comment: Ha. You've edited the question to say that you [want to read a CSV file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22144048/1269037) actually.

Comment: Classic [XY Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341). See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377

Answer (score 6):

Just skip the first line, then read the rest.

```
<>;                # read and discard a line
while (<>) {       # loop over the other lines
    print $_
}
```

**UPDATE**: after you've [edited the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22143967/revisions), it turns out you want something completely different, to

#### read a CSV file in Perl

That is a completely different question, and what you should have asked for in the first place. The answer is to use an established library, like [CSV::Slurp](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV::Slurp)

Comment: it is giving included first line    open my $fh, '<', '/home/ejaiarv/Reports_csv/LTE_Previous/LTE_AnalysisToolBox.txt' or die "'/home/ejaiarv/Reports_csv/LTE_Previous/LTE_AnalysisToolBox.txt': $!";
my $line;
while( <$fh> ) {
    print $_;
    }

Comment: @user2503377 That code does not include `<$fh>` like the code in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just skip line number ([`$.`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24.)) 1, perhaps using [`next`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/next.html), like this:

```
while (<>) {
    next if ($. == 1);
    print $_;
}
```

[Live demo.](http://ideone.com/iL7Kt9)

Comment: That will needlessly test whether the script is reading the first line. Not that it really matters, since the bottleneck is the file system, but why not just [read and discard the first line beforehand](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22144048/1269037)?.

Comment: @DanDascalescu: Your answer may run more efficiently, +1.

Answer (score -1):

u can skip the first line while reading the file itself

ex.

```
open(IN,"cat filename|tail -n +2|") || die "can not open file :$!";
while(<IN>){
     //process further
}
close(IN);
```

Comment: Is this an entry into the contest for *inefficient* ways to skip processing the first line of a file in Perl? If so, you win vs. Naghaveer and Ram.

Comment: Why would you use a system call to do that, when it is entirely possible in Perl? This is a common mistake for people learning Perl, because they do not know what modules to load to get a certain functionality. In this case, there is no module required at all. Please take a look at the other answers, especially the one by Dan and John. Also, please take the time to format your answer and use punctuation. I know Perl has a lot of punctuation by itself, but English should have as well.